# An OLD anime about a boy with "demonic" powers joins with 2 others to fight aliens who use humans for genetics experiments

Tags: story-identification, anime, genetics

The Boy's upbringing was similar to that of Goku from Dragonball.  Once the people of his village found out about the boy, they burn Grandpa's home to the ground around them killing the old man. The boy escapes fire and laments grandpa's death. Later he finds a girl who can transform into a creature like he can. Later, another person comes in to complete the trio.  One day he sees strange people with monster(or robot?) enforcers herding people from the village and when they hurt an old woman, the boy intervenes.  He discovers later that they are doing genetic experiments to save their Alien race.

Among the aliens, there is political intrigue and friction between the scientist alien and his companions. There is also interest in the new human threat (the boy) since the earth was supposed to be weak and easy to conquer.

The anime's name was listed as "ONI" but I'm not sure if that was the real (or full) name. I'm also not sure if the anime was ever finished. I bought it as a VHS tape from a Comic-Con back in 1990 but it only had 4 or 6 episodes on it. The preview at the end of the tape said the next Episode was called: Iolite. The only other info I have is the ED got considerable play due to its dramatic slow, heavy Rock bass guitar chords at the beginning. (1-2, pause, 1-2, pause, 1-2, pause, da, da, da, da, da-dahh! repeat)  I cannot find ANYTHING about this old anime on the web.  The only references listed are either for the game Oni, the hentai OniAi, and to movies, games, and anime that came out recently.  I need to finish this story if it exists, or at least hear the ed again.  I hope you folks can help me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is ***[Touma Kishinden Oni](https://myanimelist.net/anime/2366/Touma_Kishinden_Oni)*** (1995-1996).

From MyAnimeList:

> Shuramaru is hated and feared by the villagers for his unusual powers. He thinks he is human, but... is he?

> *Touma Kishinden Oni* is an original story set in the universe of the Oni series of role-playing video games. It aired within the Anime Asaichi programming block of TV Tokyo.

From [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=5374):

> Plot Summary: Shuramaru thinks he is a normal human. Then one day a group of strong fighters appear and Shuramaru's life is turned upside down, revealing a power he never know he had.

According to [this page](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=5374&page=25) from Anime News Network, the eighth episode is named "Iolite".

In the middle of the third episode, the antagonists capture the boy in a net, and he transforms into an armoured humanoid creature to free himself. The other villagers witness this, and flee in terror.

Later in the same episode, the boy is sitting with an old man in a hut, and the other villagers set fire to it, which results in the old man's death.

(Judging by a scene just before this, it appears the old man found the boy as a baby in the woods years earlier, and adopted him; a secret he'd kept until that episode.)

In the [fifth episode](https://youtu.be/1oHlFJUnemU?t=190), the boy meets a pink-haired girl and a tall male who can also transform into humanoid creatures.

Comment: Logic Dictates, THIS IS IT!  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Nehemiah - If this answer is correct, please don't forget to mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. You'll know if you've done it correctly because the check mark will turn green, and you'll receive +2 [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).